# Will my Python script still run while screen saver is on?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur, python

If I'm running a Python script locally on my MacBook Terminal prompt (MacBook Pro Laptop running on BigSur) and the computers screensaver comes off while it's idle, will my script still run? What if it means I have to re-enter my MacBook login password? Does that make a difference?

Keep in mind, it's not going into Sleep mode (At least I don't think it is? If my music is still playing, I imagine it's not on Sleep mode). As far as I can tell, it's just a screensaver but I do get "locked out" and have to log back in, so I'm not sure if that's matters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You Python script will continue to run even if the screen saver comes up. Your computer is not technically sleeping.

If you want to ensure your computer does not go to sleep while your Python script is running, you can install the following app:

- https://keepingyouawake.app